# IsAuthenticated property is still false after user authentication in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a logged in user in my MVC web application, but `IsAuthenticated` property in my `Hub` class is still false. Here is my log in and redirection sequences:

1. User submits a `Login` form.
2. Application validates user information.
3. Application creates `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and encrypts ticket using `FormsAuthentication` class.
4. Application adds encrypted ticket to response cookies in `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName` path.
5. Then I redirect it to a view that start SignalR connection, when I check is user is authenticated or not in override `OnConnected` method, I find that it is still false.

How should I handle this issue, I don't have any problem with authorization in SignalR 1.1, I'm using same code but this time with SignalR 2.0.

**Update:** *Actually it's not still false in SignalR Hub class it's false in all over application domain.*

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013, default MVC template uses ASP.Net Identity authentication system and puts `<authentication mode="None" />` in web.config, so this prevents application to creates `HttpCookie`. I just change it to `<authentication mode="Forms" />` and now it's working.

Comment: I still get the isAuthenticated false after setting above mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you add cookie into response by yourself, you need to resolve it by yourself as well.

```
if(Login(model.UserName, model.Password)){
    // ecrypt user data and add to cookie
    // your code
}

// Global file code
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // decrypt cookie and set current principal
    // your code

    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

In additional, you need a customer principal class to store user info if traditional GenericPrincipal does not fit.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch After getting value from cookie, you need to decrypt the string value if you encrypted it while writing cookie, and you'd better to know more things about IPrincipal interface.

Comment: Great! It Works (SignarR + existing cookie)